# Usage of 'AS' in a sentence

Tags: grammar

(1) The body may then begin to attack itself, **as suggested** by the rising incidence of autoimmune diseases with advancing age.

(2) The planting tree lines within roadside landscape may naturally force birds to fly higher above roads, **as was shown** in the Netherlands.

My questions are
First, What is the grammatical use of 'as' in each of two sentences? Both of them are conjunctions? Or . . .? ?

Second, can i replace 'suggested ' with 'was suggested ' so that the part could be ' as was suggested ' in (1)? And how about 'as shown ' in (2)?

Comment: Both instances of ***as*** above introduce ***adverbial clauses*** (consisting of all text up to the end of each sentence). Such clauses can optionally appear at the beginning of the sentence (because they're ***whole sentence** adverbs*), or *sometimes* can validly be placed somewhere ***within*** the remaining text. Note that *as was suggested* is far  more "tentative" than *as was shown*.